# Python subprocess git commit message only accepting single string

Tags: python, git

Using python subprocess to commit changes to a git branch, the -m message will only accept single string

I am using python 3 to loop through a directory to commit changes for all xml files.
I have tried using double quotes and single quotes for the message, neither have worked. I also tried using f and r and both failed.

```py
add=subprocess.Popen([gitPath,'git add .'],cwd=cd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess.Popen.wait(add)

commit=subprocess.Popen([gitPath,f"git commit -m 'no message spacing works'"],cwd=cd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

subprocess.Popen.wait(commit)

push=subprocess.Popen([gitPath,'git push origin DEV:PyTesting'],cwd=cd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess.Popen.wait(push)
```

I would like to be able to use regular text strings, including spaces, to put in the input commit message. When I use "no message spacing works" in the script the errors are error: pathspec 'message' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'spacing' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'works'' did not match any file(s) known to git

If I use `git commit -m 'no message spacing works'` in bash, it is accepted. What am I missing in the script to allow multiple strings?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Odds are you have quoting for the intermediate shell wrong and that you'll find the problem yourself. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I shortened the code in my example.Thank you for the links for tour and how to ask!

Answer (score 3):

I think you are passing arguments to Popen the wrong way. If you pass a list then each argument should be a separate list element. That way you don't even have to bother with quotes. So `git commit -m 'no message spacing works'` should be passed as `['git', 'commit', '-m', 'no message spacing works']`. See also the examples in the reference documentation of Popen.